# How to make MS Access tick or check box work with MySQL or SQL

Tags: mysql, ms-access, ms-access-2007

I am using MS Access 2007 as a front-end application, which links by ODBC with MySQL.

The problem is that the Access form interprets tickbox as -1 for TRUE while MySql/Sql interprets 1 as TRUE. So tick or check boxes do not work for TRUE state on Access forms.

If I write code behind (before update event) , then a single form should work with an ubound control (not linked to a data field), but on on the so-called "continuos form" when a control is unbound it will change its state **when ticked** not just on that record/row but on all rows.

Unless I can tell the Access form to change the tick-box true/false interpretation I am not sure how to use it on a continuous form.

Any solutions or hints?

Comment: There's something wrong with your ODBC driver -- the translation from -1 to 1 should be happening transparently in the driver. Have you defined the field in MySQL as a Boolean field, or as a TINYINT? I don't know what versions of MySQL support Boolean data type or not, but that might be the problem. Do this: in the TABLES tab in Access, try designing any table with a Boolean field in it (you'll get a notice that you can't actually save changes, but ignore that), and see what data type the field is defined as IN ACCESS terms. My bet is that it will be seen by Access as an Integer...

Comment: MySQL has tinyint and bit fields for this. In this case it is using tinyint. In Access table it shows as a number/integer. The Access form works with tinyint as it would place -1 in MySQL table, but then I would have to change some queries not to test fot TRUE but for -1

Comment: For compatibility, you should never test for TRUE -- test for Not False, which will always be correct, since FALSE is 0 in all Boolean representations.